# Keep getting Unresolved reference 'By' in Selenium

Tags: selenium

im keep getting Unresolved reference 'By'

here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/home?project_type=campaign&project_timing=all&sort=trending")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
vegetable = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tomatoes")
```

here is an image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to import `By` 
`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

whole code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/home?project_type=campaign&project_timing=all&sort=trending")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
vegetable = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tomatoes")
```

Answer (score 4):

add the reference

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```